# How to create a set of elements without knowing the type of the element?

Tags: module, ocaml, functor, first-class-modules

I'm running into problems around recursive/mutually referential module definitions trying to use Caml's Map/Set stuff. I really want ones that just work on types, not modules. I feel like it should be possible to do this with first-class modules, but I'm failing to make the syntax work.

The signature I want is:

```
module type NonFunctorSet = sig
  type 'a t
  val create : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a t
  val add : 'a t -> 'a -> 'a t
  val remove : 'a t -> 'a -> 'a t
  val elements : 'a t -> 'a list
end
```

Possibly with other `Caml.Set` functions included. My idea for how this would work is something like:

```
type 'a t = {
 m : (module Caml.Set.S with type elt = 'a);
 set : m.t
}

let create (compare : 'a -> 'a -> t) =
    module m = Caml.Set.Make(struct type t = 'a let compare = compare end) in
    let set = m.empty in
    {m = m; set = set;}
end
```

But that doesn't work for a number of reasons; 'a isn't exposed in the right places, I can't reference m.t in the same record where m was defined, etc.

Is there a version of this that works?

Adding more context about my use case:

I have two modules, `Region` and `Tribe`. `Tribe` needs access to a lot of the interface of `Region`, so I am currently creating `Tribe` as a functor, `MakeTribe(Region : RegionT)`.  `Region` mostly doesn't need to know about `Tribe`, but it does need to be able to store a mutable collection of `Tribe.t` that represent the tribes living in that region.

So, somehow or other, I need a `RegionT` like

```
module type RegionT = sig
  type <region>
  val get_local_tribes : <region> -> <tribes>
  val add_tribe : <region> -> <tribe> -> unit
  ...
end
```

I don't really care about the specific syntax of `<tribe>`, `<tribes>` and `<region>` in this, so long as the fully built `Tribe` module can know that `Region.get_local_tribes`, etc, will yield an actual `Tribe.t`
The circular dependency problem is that the type `<tribe>` does not exist until the module `Tribe` is created. My idea so far has been to have `RegionT.t` actually be `'a RegionT.t`, and then `Tribe` could simply refer to `Tribe.t Region.t`. This is all fine if I'm satisfied with keeping a `<tribe> list` inside `Region`, but I want it to be a set.

I feel this should be possible based on the following example code :

```
module Example : sig
  type t
  val compare : t -> t -> int
end = struct
  type t = int
  let compare = Int.compare
end

module ExampleSet = Caml.Set.Make(struct type t = Example.t let compare = Example.compare end)
```

All that `Example` exposes in its interface is a type and a function from two instances of that type to an int; why is that more than having a `'a -> 'a -> int`, which has the same things?

Comment: "Is there a version of this that works?" Yes! `opam install base` :) or `opam install core_kernel`. All Janestreet standard sets and maps are polymorphic and do not require functors.  And it looks like, from `Caml`, that you're already using Base, so what is really your question about?

Comment: @ivg Could you give me an example of the syntax of that? Every time I try to use Core Map/Set I get lost trying to provide valid comparators, witnesses, s-exp converters, etc, which is why I fell back to using Caml in the first place.

Comment: I added the answer and edited your question to reflect what you have said in the comments. Does it work for you?

Comment: I edited your question a yet another time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using Polymoprhic Sets and Maps from the Base Library

In Base and Core libraries, from Jane Street, ordered data structures, such as maps, sets, hash tables, and hash sets, are all implemented as polymorphic data structures, instead of functorized versions as in the vanilla OCaml standard library.

You can read about them more in the Real World OCaml [Maps and Hashtbales](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/maps-and-hashtables.html) chapter. But here are quick recipes. When you see a comparator in the function interface, e.g., in `Map.empty` what it actually wants you is to give you a *module* that implements the comparator interface. The good news is that most of the modules in Base/Core are implementing it, so you don't have to worry or know anything about this to use it, e.g.,

```
# open Base;;
# let empty = Map.empty (module Int);;
val empty : (Base.Int.t, 'a, Base.Int.comparator_witness) Base.Map.t =
  <abstr>
# Map.add empty 1 "one";;
- : (Base.Int.t, string, Base.Int.comparator_witness) Base.Map.t
    Base.Map.Or_duplicate.t
= `Ok <abstr>
```

So the simple rule, if you want a set,map,hashtable,hashset where the key element has type `foo`, just pass `(module Foo)` as a comparator.

Now, what if you want to make a mapping from your custom type? E.g., a pair of ints that you would like to compare in lexicographical order.

First of all, we need to define sexp_of and compare functions. For our type. We will use ppx derivers for it, but it is easy to make it manually if you need.

```
 module Pair = struct
   type t = int * int [@@deriving compare, sexp_of]
 end
```

Now, to create a comparator, we just need to use the `Base.Comparator.Make` functor, e.g.,

```
 module Lexicographical_order = struct 
    include Pair
    include Base.Comparator.Make(Pair)
 end
```

So now we can do,

```
# let empty = Set.empty (module Lexicographical_order);;
val empty :
  (Lexicographical_order.t, Lexicographical_order.comparator_witness)
  Base.Set.t = <abstr>
# Set.add empty (1,2);;
- : (Lexicographical_order.t, Lexicographical_order.comparator_witness)
    Base.Set.t
= <abstr>
```

Despite that Base's data structures are polymorphic they strictly require that the module that provides the comparator is instantiated and known. You can just use the compare function to create a polymorphic data structure because Base will instantiate a witness type for each defined compare function and capture it in the data structure type to enable binary methods. Anyway, it is a complex issue, read on for easier (and harder) solutions.

## Instantiating Sets on mutually dependent modules

In fact, OCaml supports mutually recursive funtors and although I would suggest you to break the recursion by introducing a common abstraction on which both Region and Tribe depend, you can still encode your problem in OCaml, e.g.,

```
module rec Tribe : sig
  type t
  val create : string -> t
  val compare : t -> t -> int
  val regions : t -> Region.t list
end = struct
  type t = string * Region.t list
  let create name = name,[]
  let compare (x,_) (y,_) = String.compare x y
  let regions (_,r) = r
end
and Region : sig
  type t
  val empty : t
  val add_tribe : Tribe.t -> t -> t
  val tribes : t -> Tribe.t list
end = struct
  module Tribes = Set.Make(Tribe)
  type t = Tribes.t
  let empty = Tribes.empty
  let add_tribe = Tribes.add
  let tribes = Tribes.elements
end
```

## Breaking the Dependency Loop

A much better solution would be to redesign your modules and break the dependency loop. The simplest approach would be just to choose some identifier that will be used to compare tribes, e.g., by their unique names,

```
module Region : sig
  type 'a t
  val empty : 'a t
  val add_tribe : string -> 'a -> 'a t -> 'a t
  val tribes : 'a t -> 'a list
end = struct
  module Tribes = Map.Make(String)
  type 'a t = 'a Tribes.t
  let empty = Tribes.empty
  let add_tribe = Tribes.add
  let tribes r = Tribes.bindings r |> List.map snd

end

module Tribe : sig
  type t
  val create : string -> t
  val name : t -> string
  val regions : t -> t Region.t list
  val conquer : t Region.t -> t -> t Region.t
end = struct
  type t = Tribe of string * t Region.t list
  let create name = Tribe (name,[])
  let name (Tribe (name,_)) = name
  let regions (Tribe (_,r)) = r
  let conquer region tribe =
    Region.add_tribe (name tribe) tribe region
end
```

There are also tons of other options and in general, when you have mutual dependencies it is actually an indicator of a problem in your design. So, I would still revisit the design stage and eschew the circular dependencies.

## Creating Polymorphic Sets using the Vanilla OCaml Standard Library

It is not an easy task, especially if you need to handle operations that involve several sets, e.g., `Set.union`. The problem is that `Set.Make` is generating a new type for the set per each `compare` function so when we need to union two sets it is hard for us to prove to the OCaml compiler that they were created from the same type. It is possible but really painful, I am showing how to do this only to discourage you from doing this (and to showcase OCaml's dynamic typing capabilities).

First of all we need a witness type that will reify an OCaml type for the set into a concrete value.

```
type _ witness = ..


module type Witness = sig
  type t
  type _ witness += Id : t witness
end
```

Now we can define our polymorphic set as an existential that holds the set itself and the module with operations. It also holds the `tid` (for type identifier) that we will later use to recover the type `'s` of the set.

```
type 'a set = Set : {
    set : 's;
    ops : (module Set.S with type elt = 'a and type t = 's);
    tid : (module Witness with type t = 's);
  } -> 'a set
```

Now we can write the `create` function that will take the compare function and turn it into a set,

```
let create : type a s. (a -> a -> int) -> a set =
  fun compare ->
  let module S = Set.Make(struct
      type t = a
      let compare = compare
    end) in
  let module W = struct
    type t = S.t
    type _ witness += Id : t witness
  end in
  Set {
    set = S.empty;
    ops = (module S);
    tid = (module W);
  }
```

The caveat here is that each call to `create` will generate a new instance of the set type `'s` so we can compare/union/etc two sets that were created with the same `create` function. In other words, all sets in our implementation shall share the same ancestor. But before that lets take a pain and implement at least two operations, `add` and `union`,

```
let add : type a. a -> a set -> a set =
  fun elt (Set {set; tid; ops=(module Set)}) -> Set {
      set = Set.add elt set;
      ops = (module Set);
      tid;
    }

let union : type a. a set -> a set -> a set =
  fun (Set {set=s1; tid=(module W1); ops=(module Set)})
    (Set {set=s2; tid=(module W2)}) ->
    match W1.Id with
    | W2.Id -> Set {
        set = Set.union s1 s2;
        tid = (module W1);
        ops = (module Set);
      }
    | _ -> failwith "sets are potentially using different types"
```

Now, we can play with it a bit,

```
# let empty = create compare;;
val empty : '_weak1 set = Set {set = <poly>; ops = <module>; tid = <module>}
# let x1 = add 1 empty;;
val x1 : int set = Set {set = <poly>; ops = <module>; tid = <module>}
# let x2 = add 2 empty;;
val x2 : int set = Set {set = <poly>; ops = <module>; tid = <module>}
# let x3 = union x1 x2;;
val x3 : int set = Set {set = <poly>; ops = <module>; tid = <module>}
# let x4 = create compare;;
val x4 : '_weak2 set = Set {set = <poly>; ops = <module>; tid = <module>}
# union x3 x4;;
Exception: Failure "sets are potentially using different types".
#
```

Comment: I appreciate the work you put into this answer, but it runs back into the problems that led me to this question in the first place. I want a lightweight interface that can generate a `'a set` just from a `'a -> `a -> int` , which is all that `Caml.Set` requires. Your example requires the base type be known/wrapped in a visible module. The reason that doesn't work for me is that the type I want to work with is defined in a module that relies on this one, so that would introduce circular dependencies. I'm also trying to avoid `sexp`, `deriving`, etc, when all I want is a set of a custom type.

Comment: I think it is an x/y problem. You probably are trying to solve much easier problem by overcoming a very fundamental problem. There is no easy way to generate `'a set` from the `compare` function. You can either go through GADT and existentials (pain) or reimplement the AVL tree from scratch and storing the compare function in the tree (this is what Base did, also very painful). No cheap solution here. You need to add more information about your use case. There is no need to introduce any circular dependencies, you can easily define a map for the type that you just define.

Comment: Edited more context into OP. I don't understand your statement that there's no easy way to generate a set from a compare function - maybe I'm missing something major, or maybe we're describing different things. I also edited an example where (I think!) I do exactly that, into the end of my post.

Comment: well, I meantime edited my post to show how hard it is to solve your problem, well at least the way you described. You were trying to solve a much more general problem than you really need. After the edit, I can tell that you indeed are trying to solve a simple problem through solving a hard problem. Also, if you just need the mutable collection and polymorphic comparison function works with your tribes, then you can stick with OCaml's standard Hashbl.t. Also, are you sure that you will never need to union two tribes? Because, as you can see from the edition to my post, it would be non-trivial

Comment: @EdwardPeters, I am done. TL;DR; remove the dependency, if can't use recursive modules.

Comment: Well, thanks for the time you put into this, I do appreciate it. I am going with something close to what you suggested, with a set generated from a more visible ID type. I'm still trying to parse your "polymorphic sets" answer, though I think it goes very far beyond what I wanted (I don't need `union` et all). If you don't mind one more question, can you point me to what the `a.` in `let add : type a. a -> a set -> a set =` and the `s.` in `let create : type a s. (a -> a -> int) -> a set =` mean? I'm not familiar with that syntax and googling punctuation is hard.

Comment: It is a locally abstract type. If a type is freshly created in a scope of a function then it  either shall not escape it (i.e., values of that type must belong to the scope of the function) or be bound to the scope of the caller. It is much like passing an implicit type reference to the function that is then filled with the freshly generated type. Also, if you don't need union, then you can remove `tid` and all the witness stuff.